# How to specify to show only some specifics field in a select * query output in MySql?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have the following **MySql** table:

```
mysql> describe drft1_menu;
+-------------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| Field             | Type                | Null | Key | Default             | Extra          |
+-------------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| id                | int(11)             | NO   | PRI | NULL                | auto_increment |
| menutype          | varchar(24)         | NO   | MUL | NULL                |                |
| title             | varchar(255)        | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
| alias             | varchar(255)        | NO   | MUL | NULL                |                |
| note              | varchar(255)        | NO   |     |                     |                |
| path              | varchar(1024)       | NO   | MUL | NULL                |                |
| link              | varchar(1024)       | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
| type              | varchar(16)         | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
| published         | tinyint(4)          | NO   |     | 0                   |                |
| parent_id         | int(10) unsigned    | NO   |     | 1                   |                |
| level             | int(10) unsigned    | NO   |     | 0                   |                |
| component_id      | int(10) unsigned    | NO   | MUL | 0                   |                |
| checked_out       | int(10) unsigned    | NO   |     | 0                   |                |
| checked_out_time  | timestamp           | NO   |     | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |                |
| browserNav        | tinyint(4)          | NO   |     | 0                   |                |
| access            | int(10) unsigned    | NO   |     | 0                   |                |
| img               | varchar(255)        | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
| template_style_id | int(10) unsigned    | NO   |     | 0                   |                |
| params            | text                | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
| lft               | int(11)             | NO   | MUL | 0                   |                |
| rgt               | int(11)             | NO   |     | 0                   |                |
| home              | tinyint(3) unsigned | NO   |     | 0                   |                |
| language          | char(7)             | NO   | MUL |                     |                |
| client_id         | tinyint(4)          | NO   | MUL | 0                   |                |
+-------------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
24 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

As you can see there is many fields and if I try to execute:

```
select * from describe drft1_menu;
```

the obtained output is terrible. What have I to do tho show only some specific fields? (for example only the id, title and alias fields of all contained records)

Tnx

Andrea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For only one column (or similar-named columns) you can use:

```
SHOW FIELDS FROM `drft1_menu` LIKE 'id'
```

-for `id` column. But that may not answer the question in common case. For that there's `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` database (sample below for columns `id`, `title`):

```
SELECT 
  * 
FROM 
  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns 
WHERE 
  TABLE_SCHEMA='database_name' 
  AND 
  TABLE_NAME='drft1_menu' 
  AND 
  COLUMN_NAME IN ('id', 'title');
```

-output will not look like `DESCRIBE`, but will provide same information. The good thing about this, however, is that you can specify only those description fields that you need (for example, only `COLUMN_NAME` and `DATA_TYPE` fields)

Answer (score 1):

Select id, title, alias from drft1_menu

Comment: This has nothing to do with answer

Comment: I beg to differ.  OP Wanted 3 columns.  OP requested ***id*** , ***title*** , and ***alias*** .  I shouldn't have to repeat what several others have stated.  OP needed to remove * from her query statement as it obtains all data.  In doing so we select the three items that she did want.

Comment: No. Please, read with paying attention. OP doesn't need data. He needs schema.

Answer (score 1):

Use this query:

```
SELECT id, title, alias FROM drft1_menu;
```

Comment: ..doh :) Quote from OP: `select * from describe drft1_menu;` - he wants SCHEMA, not DATA :)

Answer (score 0):

So far as `DESCRIBE` is a shortcut to `SHOW COLUMNS`, you can use this last one and use its filter to filter to some pattern.

```
SHOW COLUMNS FROM drft1_menu LIKE 'pattern';
```

Answer (score 0):

To get only specific fields from the table you can simply use

```
select SELECT id, title, alias,etc.. FROM drft1_menu;
```

You can use condition in the select query to obtain desired output.
For example if you need only id column and also the id should be less than 10,use

```
select SELECT id from drft1_menu where id<10
```